# call a jython file from another program

Tags: jython

can i call a jython file from another jython program and execute that .

Also i know os.system(cmd.exe)get the system prompt . is it possible that i can trigger cmd.exe and  cmd.exe gets poped up into the screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using "CMD /C JYTHON MYPROG.PY"

Comment: Sometimes it it easier to create `.bat` file and call it from other programs. In such `.bat` you can add `pause` at end of the file, redirect stdout/stderr etc.

Comment: Correct. Thats something I do all the time